# Generic types not equal

Tags: c#, .net, generics

The code segment below prints out "The types ARE NOT the same.".  Why?  I am aware of the fact that using `interfaceOnMyType.GetGenericTypeDefinition()` will solve the problem, but why should I have to do that?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var myType = typeof(Baz<>);
        var interfaceOnMyType = myType.GetInterfaces().SingleOrDefault();
        var exactType = typeof(IBar<>);
        if (exactType == interfaceOnMyType)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The types ARE the same.");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The types ARE NOT the same.");
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

interface IBar<T>
{
}

class Baz<T> : IBar<T>
{
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is that `interfaceOnMyType.IsGenericTypeDefinition` returns false, whilst `myType.IsGenericTypeDefinition` and `exactType.IsGenericTypeDefinition` both return true. That is, just because you're retrieving a non-constructed generic type from a generic type definition does not mean that the type you retrieve is itself a generic type definition.

Answer (score 4):

```
interfaceOnMyType.GetGenericTypeDefinition()
```

returns you the closed constructed type of the interface which is different from the type returned from

```
typeof(IBar<>)
```

[Here is the MSDN article on `GetGenericTypeDefinition`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getgenerictypedefinition.aspx), and here is a good quote from it explaining how it works:

> Given a `Type` object representing this constructed type, the `GetGenericTypeDefinition` method returns the generic type definition.

---

Edit (the answer above is correct in some cases but wrong in this one):

I think I may have found it now.  The reason that the type comparison is failing is because the `Type` returned from `myType.GetInterfaces()` is close to but not identical to the type of the interface itself.

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.fullname.aspx):

> If you use the `BaseType` property to obtain the base type of `Derived`, the `FullName` property of the resulting Type object returns `null` (Nothing in Visual Basic). To get a non-null `FullName`, you can use the `GetGenericTypeDefinition` method to get the generic type definition.

So I think this is the problem you are seeing.  Since base interfaces are retrieved via `GetInterfaces` any type retrieved by that call will not have a `FullName` ([source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.basetype.aspx)).  Since it does not have a `FullName` the types will fail in comparison.

What I orginally wrote would be true if you were comparing the constructed type which you are not.  So unfortunately my first answer is dead wrong - I have left it so that the comments left will make sense.

Comment: Nope, they are the same - try it.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
            Console.WriteLine("{0}", (null != exactType.FullName) ? exactType.FullName : "null");
            Console.WriteLine("{0}", (null != interfaceOnMyType.FullName) ? interfaceOnMyType.FullName : "null");
```

The output is:

test.Program+IBar`1 
 null

This supports the findings posted here by Andrew Hare.